# Koma script: using the fontstyle of chapter and section for a paragraph

Tags: fonts, koma-script, chapters, paragraphs

is there a way in koma script to use the fontstyle of chapter, section, subsection etc. for the typesetting of a paragraph in the text? Thx, Harald

```
\documentclass[
    10pt,
    twoside,
    toc=listofnumbered,
    listof=flat,
    headinclude,
    footinclude,
    index=numbered
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setparsizes{5.5mm}{5pt}{0pt plus 1fil}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[ 
  beforeskip=1pt, 
  afterskip=10mm,
  afterindent=false
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[ 
  beforeskip=5mm, 
  afterskip=5mm,
  afterindent=false
]{section}

\begin{document}
\chapter{MyChapter}
\blindtext[1]

\noindent Should look like MyChapter.
\section{MySection}
\blindtext[1]

\noindent Should look like MySection.
\end{document}
```

[image: reuse_fontstyle_of_chapter]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font settings of the chapter (section) title are stored in the font elements `dispostion` and `chapter` (`section`). They can be enabled using

`\usekomafont{disposition}\usekomafont{chapter}`

or

`\usekomafont{disposition}\usekomafont{section}`

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
    10pt,
    twoside,
    toc=listofnumbered,
    listof=flat,
    headinclude,
    footinclude,
    index=numbered
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setparsizes{5.5mm}{5pt}{0pt plus 1fil}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[ 
  beforeskip=1pt, 
  afterskip=10mm,
  afterindent=false
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[ 
  beforeskip=5mm, 
  afterskip=5mm,
  afterindent=false
]{section}

\begin{document}
\chapter{MyChapter}
\blindtext[1]

\noindent {\usekomafont{disposition}\usekomafont{chapter}Should look like MyChapter.\par}
\section{MySection}
\blindtext[1]

\noindent {\usekomafont{disposition}\usekomafont{section}Should look like MySection.\par}
\end{document}
```

You can also define your own font elements using `\newkomafont`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
    10pt,
    twoside,
    toc=listofnumbered,
    listof=flat,
    headinclude,
    footinclude,
    index=numbered
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setparsizes{5.5mm}{5pt}{0pt plus 1fil}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[ 
  beforeskip=1pt, 
  afterskip=10mm,
  afterindent=false
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[ 
  beforeskip=5mm, 
  afterskip=5mm,
  afterindent=false
]{section}

\newkomafont{parchapter}{\usekomafont{disposition}\usekomafont{chapter}}
\newkomafont{parsection}{\usekomafont{disposition}\usekomafont{section}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{MyChapter}
\blindtext[1]

\noindent {\usekomafont{parchapter}Should look like MyChapter.\par}
\section{MySection}
\blindtext[1]

\noindent {\usekomafont{parsection}Should look like MySection.\par}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's it. Thx. Harald

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}%  needed when using Computer Modern typefaces
\documentclass[
fontsize = 10pt,
twoside,
toc=listofnumbered,
listof=flat,
headinclude,
footinclude,
index=numbered
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setparsizes{5.5mm}{5pt}{0pt plus 1fil}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[ 
beforeskip=1pt, 
afterskip=10mm,
afterindent=false
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[ 
beforeskip=5mm, 
afterskip=5mm,
afterindent=false
]{section}

\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %

\begin{document}
    \chapter{MyChapter}

    \blindtext[1]
        
    \noindent Should look like \textbf{\huge MyChapter}.
    
    \section{MySection} 
        
    \blindtext[1]
        
    \noindent Should look like \textbf{\Large MySection}.
\end{document}
```

Chapter and sections titles use the sans serif font.

`\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` in the preamble will set this font family globally.

[image: xaf]